# Making a simple boss in tModloader

Tags: c#

So I'm not sure if im missing a reference that should be downloaded or something. but when i tried to apply the "npc.width = 160;" for example it had a little squiggly line below npc. after i added it in uppercase it seemed to go away. Please help me as im just trying to make a little mod for me and my friends to test out, nothing special just want it to atleast run

```
using Terraria;
using IL.Terraria.ID;
using Terraria.ID;
using Terraria.ModLoader;

namespace RUINATION.NPCs
{
    [AutoloadBossHead]
    public class Heiden : ModNPC
    {
        public override void SetStaticDefaults()
        {
            DisplayName.SetDefault("Angry Heiden");
            Terraria.Main.npcFrameCount[ModContent.NPCType<Heiden>()] = Terraria.Main.npcFrameCount[Terraria.ID.NPCID.SkeletronHead];
        }
        public override void SetDefaults()
        {
            NPC.aiStyle = Terraria.ID.NPCID.SkeletronHead;
            NPC.width = 160;
            NPC.height = 240;
            NPC.damage = 50;
            NPC.defense = 20;
            NPC.lifeMax = 10000;
            NPC.HitSound = Terraria.ID.SoundID.NPCHit1;
            NPC.DeathSound = Terraria.ID.SoundID.NPCDeath1;
            NPC.knockBackResist = 0f;
            NPC.boss = true;
            NPC.lavaImmune = true;
            NPC.noGravity = true;
            NPC.noTileCollide = true;
            NPC.dontTakeDamage = true;
            NPC.netAlways = true;
            TerrariabossBag = mod.ItemType("HeidenBossBag");
        }

        public override void AI()
        {
            NPC.SkeletronAI(NPC, ref NPC.ai);
        }

        public override void NPCLoot()
        {
            int choice = Terraria.Main.rand.Next(4); // Generate a random number between 0 and 3

            if (Terraria.Main.expertMode)
            {
                NPC.DropBossBags();
            }
            else
            {
                if (choice == 0)
                {
                    Terraria.Item.NewItem(NPC.Center, Terraria.ItemID.GoldCoin, Terraria.Main.rand.Next(10, 21));
                }
                if (choice == 1)
                {
                    Terraria.Item.NewItem(NPC.Center, Terraria.ItemID.LifeCrystal, Terraria.Main.rand.Next(2, 4));
                }
                if (choice == 2)
                {
                    Terraria.Item.NewItem(NPC.Center, Terraria.ItemID.ManaCrystal, Terraria.Main.rand.Next(2, 4));
                }
                if (choice == 3)
                {
                    Terraria.Item.NewItem(NPC.Center, Terraria.ItemID.HealingPotion, Terraria.Main.rand.Next(10, 21));
                }
                TerrariaItem.bossBag[mod.ItemType("HeidenBossBag")] = true;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag irrelevant languages, this isn't c++